# Meaning of "helpings of drive"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I found this expression in a book I'm reading, and I'm having trouble understanding it:

> All the superstars I’ve known have **heaping helpings of drive** and they’ll continually hound people to further their careers.

What does "heaping helpings of drive" mean in this context?

Comment: It sounds very unnatural and may be a mistake/typo. "Heaped helpings" would be slightly better, implying a big helping. I'm guessing it's not from a native speaker, or possibly they meant to say "heaped" but were confused by the "ping" ending in the following word.

Comment: @StuartF  "Heaping" is the usual idiom I've heard.

Comment: @StuartF I think this is a BrEng vs AmEng distinction. I'm BrEng and I'd say "heaped" as well, but I've heard AmEng say "heaping" in the same sense.

Comment: @Vicky - it is a Am.Eng vs Br.Eng distinction.  I've heard Americans talk about "heaping tablespoons". In the UK we say "heaped tablespoons", never "heaping", which sounds very odd.

Comment: @itamar - it means "lots/a large amount of motivation".  A heaping (or heaped) helping is a mataphor, with reference to large amount of food, a large serving of food (a heaped plate of food).   Drive in this sense is a noun, it means motivation.  To have drive = to have motivation.

Comment: Can any Americans explain why ‘heaping’ (and not ‘heaped’) makes sense to you?  From the other side of the Atlantic, ‘heaping’ would suggest that the plate (or whatever) is in the process of having stuff heaped upon it _while you're speaking_, which would be very odd — or, more literally, that the stuff was heaping _itself_ while you're speaking, which would be even odder!  (Would you similarly refer to a plate of ‘poaching eggs’ with ‘mashing potato’ and ‘grating cheese’?)

Comment: @gidds I think of "a heaping tablespoon of flour" as similar to "a towering stack of paper". Once I have "heaped" the material into a large pile, it is now "heaping" in that it embodies that physical form. (As I write this, I wonder whether there is a corresponding Br/Am difference for "towering" versus "towered"...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a metaphor, derived from a meal where you choose how much to take from the dish.

Someone goes to a salad bar, and the portion that this person takes is a helping.  If he takes a lot, it will heap up on the plate.

Thus a "heaping helping" of drive is a lot of drive.

Comment: +1, but this answer would be better if it explained that "drive" in this context (which might sound like a verb) is a synonym for motivation, enthusiasm, or persistence.

Comment: +1. https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&sca_esv=f25fd1d09a6b1709&sca_upv=1&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&sxsrf=ACQVn08Bu7fDljXFsJ7JQ0IV6oEOD5sGJA:1711401678728&q=%22heaping+helping%22&tbm=bks&source=lnms&prmd=ivsnmbtz&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCm4OJrJCFAxUVpIkEHeegAxgQ0pQJegQIcxAB&biw=1246&bih=638&dpr=1

Comment: A huge thank you for that. I was still a little lost, but now it all makes sense.